# Placing from XML Childnode data to Array

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

This is part of the XML:

```
<pubDate>Mon, 18 Nov 2013 10:43:28 +0100</pubDate>
  <category>Algemeen</category>
  <enclosure url="http://bin.snmmd.nl/m/m1mxwvnavj3a_sqr256.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
  <copyrightPhoto>nu.nl</copyrightPhoto>
```

I know that the following for loop places childnodes in an array.

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < berichtnr; i++) {
            //puts title in titleArray      
            titleArray[i] = rssXML.channel.item[i].title;
            //puts date in dateArray
            dateArray[i] = rssXML.channel.item[i].pubDate;
        }
```

I want to place the link from childnode enclosure url in an array. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in XML are accessed with @ sign. To reach url, you need following:

```
rssXML.channel.item[i].enclosure.@url
```

Second option is to use attribute() method. For more info see:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html